# Visual Studio 2022 suppress NU1701 by default

Tags: .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I'm working on a WPF project targeting .NET 6.0, and my task is to get rid of all the compiler warnings. One of the libraries we're using is Helix, which is giving us the NU1701 warning:

> Error NU1701  Warning As Error: Package 'HelixToolkit.Wpf.SharpDX
> 2.23.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of
> the project target framework 'net6.0-windows7.0'

I know I can suppress it, but I didn't want to cover up a potential bug by doing so. In fact, a few of the projects in our solution already had it suppressed.

Initially I thought it was done by a developer, but I just realized that VS 2022 project template has it suppressed by default (I saw it for WPF, Console App and C# Library).

[image]

Does anyone know why? Is this enough reason for me to not worry about it?

Comment: Why not target the Core version instead? https://www.nuget.org/packages/HelixToolkit.SharpDX.Core.Wpf